# Update 'Add to cart' form action with session variable using Ajax

Tags: ajax, magento, session, session-variables

I have a dropdown on the product detail page from which I can select an option, and the value of this option needs to be set in a session variable using Ajax. It works fine till this part.
What I am trying to do now is append this session variable to the 'Add to cart' form action.

This is how the form action code looks right now

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product,array('session'=>$getselected_optionvalue)) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?> class="form">
```

The form action gets updated with the right value if I refresh the page. How do I update it without refreshing or navigating away from the page?

Answer (score 2):

You could try changing the form action on the `success:` function of your ajax call.

If you're using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'path/to/url',
  ... // Other options here
  success: function(data) {
    $('#myform').attr('action', data.newAction);
  }
});
```

You just have to set the data in the controller:

```
$data = array(
  'newAction' => 'new/form/action/here',
  ... // Other data here
);

$jsonData = json_encode($data);

$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
$this->getResponse()->setBody($jsonData);

return $jsonData;
```

Make sure to set the `Content-type` header as `application/json`